# Eclipse warning about SortedMap not redeclaring equals() and hashCode()

Tags: java, eclipse, equals, hashcode, sortedmap

I have a Java POJO class that I use in my project for Jackson deserialization from JSON. This class has various members, but the important member to consider is of the type [java.util.SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html). I want to add the `equals()` and `hashCode()` to this class in order for me to compare instances of these classes with each other. Therefore, I used Eclipse's source code generation tool to create these two methods. I get the following warning message from the IDE:

> The field type 'java.util.SortedMap' does not redeclare equals() and hashCode() - the resulting code may not work correctly.

Note that my POJO object that I am trying to create `equals()` and `hashCode()` for does have members of different *java.util* interfaces, like *List* and *Map*, but there are no warning messages about lack of `equals()` or `hashCode()` for those two interfaces.

I guess that a part of the problem is that I am not sure why implementation of *SortedMap* Jackson will deserialize JSON into. There are many different implementations of the *SortedMap* interface available in my classpath and some do override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, but it is still impossible (?) to know whether one of these implementations will be choses by Jackson.

Is this warning message something that I need to worry about? Anyone know of any workarounds for this problem?

Aside: I have no desire to use Lombok in this project.

---

### Update

Filed the following bug for Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422184

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get warnings about `List` and `Map` because those interfaces do declare `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

Since `SortedMap` extends the `Map` interface which does have the methods and which should still work for `SortedMap` I think everything should work.

Comment: I would consider this a bug in the Eclipse "Generate equals() and hashCode()" wizard, since it should be able to determine that SortedMap extends another type that does declare the methods. If you want to help out, consider reporting this issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: Ah yes, `extends Map` is all that's needed to ensure that `equals()` and `hashCode` are implemented by SortedMap implementation. I missed that. I will file a bug in Eclipse. Thank you.